# vim global command only first occurrence

Tags: text-processing, vim

I was wondering if it's possible to use the :g command in vim to match with only the first occurrence of a search result.

I have a file with contents like

```
Match 01
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
Match 01
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
Match 02
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
Match 02
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
Match 03
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
Match 03
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
```

I'm trying to execute the following command to extract data

```
:g/Match 02/.,$w! /tmp/TESTING.txt
```

So it's using the global command then writes from the current line to the end of the document into /tmp/TESTING.txt

The current line though is always the last occurrence of the match so I end up with

```
Match 02
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
Match 03
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
Match 03
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
```

Instead of

```
Match 02
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
Match 02
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
Match 03
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
Match 03
    stuff 01
    stuff 02
    stuff 03
```

Which is what I want. I was wondering if it's possible to have the global command only go to the first occurrence of the match to solve this.

Comment: That's weird i thought I did, must've fumbled. Tganks for reminding me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your problem is that the cursor has ended up below the first match; my suggestion would be to tell vim to move the cursor to line 1, then execute the range/write:

```
:1 | /Match 02/,$w! /tmp/TESTING.txt
```

I removed the period, since it seems to me that you want to write a range to a file, and that range is defined as *from* the search on "Match 02" until the end `$` of the file.

Reference:

- https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2288/15963

Comment: This works perfectly, I didn't realize you could use find and pipes like that. Thanks so much for the assistance

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work for me.  The problem with your incantation appeared to be that the global match *was* matching the latter match (as it was, well, global):

```
0;/Match 02/;,$w! file
```

Answer (score 2):

Global executes the command for each match, so what is actually written to the file is `.,$` from the first match, and then `.,$` from the second match (etc). This can be observed by appending to the output file instead of clobbering the contents on each match.

```
:g/Match 02/.,$w >> TESTING
```

A macro may be more suitable; type

```
qa1G/Match 02
:.,$w! TESTING
q
```

where the line breaks above are where you need to mash the return key. Then type `:reg a` and this should look something like

```
:reg a
--- Registers ---
"a   1G/Match 02^M:.,$w! TESTING^M
```

and can be played back by typing `@a`